# compare two arrays of Objects in JavaScript and if true save new items to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, object

Good Afternoon,
I am trying to compare two arrays of objects, each object contains an id. One array comes from Stripe the other from my DB. If the ID's match then returns true and if not return false. The idea is that if there is an id that does not match then it will return false and run another function that does the updating.
Right now I am using forEach(), but I was using two for loops for both arrays, but it was not working properly. My function returns false even though there are elements in both arrays that match.
Below is my code with both methods and also the implementation.

```js
  function findCommoneID(stripeInvoice, DBInvoices) {
    var isSame = false;
    stripeInvoice.forEach((StripeElement) => {
    DBInvoices.forEach((DBElement) => {
    if(StripeElement.id === DBElement.id) {
      isSame = true
     
    } 
})
  });
  return isSame;

}


// Implementation 
app.get('/store-update-invoices', async (req, res) => {

  const stripe = require('stripe')(`${process.env.REACT_APP_Stripe_Live}`);
  const invoice = await stripe.invoices.list().catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
    
  
 
  const invoices = app.get('Invoices');

 
  if(findCommoneID(invoice.data, invoices)) {

    console.log('Ids  exist');
    return;

  } else {
    console.log('ids dont exist')

   // DBInvoices( invoice, invoices); <-- function that runs update
    
  }

    });
```

Comment: Would be useful if your code actually ran albeit with sample hardcoded data

Comment: For each of the stripe invoices find and update db invoice. The find and update on the db happens in one operation. You don't need two loops.

Comment: I have updated the findCommonId function to what I currently have per the comment below. But as of right now when I put a console.log() under the conditional it just logs the ids that match so it will always return true. Thats not what I want, because currently there is an invoice ID that is not included in the DB, but it wont update because because it keeps returning true.

Comment: Would comparing the difference between the two arrays be better using a custom function and the `.filter()` method? If there is a difference then run the update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make these changes to you `findCommoneID` function

```
function findCommoneID(stripeInvoice, DBInvoices) {
  var isSame = true;
  stripeInvoice.forEach((StripeElement) => {
    DBInvoices.forEach((DBElement) => {
        if(StripeElement.id !== DBElement.id) {
          isSame = false
          break;
        } 
    })
  });
  return isSame;
}
```

Comment: I use your solution and it works kind of, when I console.log() the stripeElement.id in the stripe forEach and the DBInvoices it logs all of the ID's, but when I log it under the If conditional, it drops the one that isn't in the database.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if that works as expected. As I understand if at least one id is not the same, then you want this function to return false

Comment: I did some slight modifications to your answer just to make it more robust, but it works! Thank you for all of your help, you helped me out immensely!

Answer (score 0):

You algorithm is flawed currently. You are checking each item in Stripe against each item in DB. Meaning unless both arrays are [X][X][X]...[X], then your check will fail.

What you want is:

```
Stripe's First element == DB's first element
Stripe's Second element == DB's second element
...
Stripe's last element == DB's last element
```

Suggested pseudocode:

```
if Stripe.length != DB.length
    return false
for (int i = 0; i < Stripe.length; i++) 
   if Stripe[i] != DB[i]
        return false

return true
```

Comment: I am looking to make sure that each of the ids in the object match. If you look at my code above you will see two for loops commented out. The problem was that when I console logged the stripe invoice array at the top of the function before the for loops it only contained two invoices when there are 8 so I’m not sure why it didn’t have all the data but the for each does

Comment: If the two arrays don't match in length, this the comparison will always fail. Try printing the .length of each array. If the lengths are not what you expect, you may have other problems in your code/configuration.